# Video quality when desktop recording is bad

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-capture

Trying to record my desktop and also audio with `RHEL6`.
I'm using the command below, but the quality of the video output is not good.
It is very blurry and I can bearly make out text on screen.
The audio is good so no issues there.

Does anyone know how the make the video quality any better?

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq -f mpeg -ar 48000 -s wvga -y sample.avi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `-sameq` option means 'same quantizer' *not* 'same quality' and is depreciated, see **[here](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f)**.

Try `-q 1` instead.

`q` being quality 1-32 (1 being highest)

Comment: `ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -r 25 -i :0.0 -q 1 -f mpeg -ar 48000 -s wvga -y sample.avi` gives an `Unrecognized option 'q'
` error?

Comment: hmm, strange, it might be because you're forcing an output format, you could try without `-f mpeg`